# Web socket client connection issue in Windows 8.1+ IE 11 + loopback not allowed

Tags: windows, websocket, internet-explorer-11, loopback

I am have created a C++ web socket server. I am trying to access it from IE 11 using web socket Javascript API. I am trying to connect to localhost.

```
function JSInit() {

try {        
    var host = "ws://127.0.0.1:25000/test";       

    remoteEngine = new WebSocket(host);
    remoteEngine.onopen = onWebSocketOpen;  
    remoteEngine.onmessage = onRecvMessage;
    remoteEngine.onclose = onWebSocketClose;
    remoteEngine.onclose = onWebSocketError;
}
catch (err) {
    alert(err.message);
}
}
```

Is there in any restriction on accessing ?Anyway to allow access to it.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the javascript or server? I have implemented this using [Alchemy](https://github.com/Olivine-Labs/Alchemy-Websockets) and [Super Web Sockets](http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/) and it works without any issues.

Comment: @iZ88 always end up in onerror callback and some time error is security error and other time it is ..nothing...R u doing any setting in IE 11?

Comment: another thing to check is if your page is hosted as https. if so you might want to try hosting the web service as a wss.

Comment: I guess localhost loopback is not allowed in IE 11.

Answer (score 1):

Localhost loop back is not allowed in IE 11 on Window 8 onwards

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/03/23/understanding-ie10-enhanced-protected-mode-network-security-addons-cookies-metro-desktop.aspx

Comment: It should be noted that the link provided in the answer discusses a utility to enable the loop back for development purposes.

Comment: For those with the ability to change this, Internet Options, Security, Local Intranet, Sites, Uncheck "Automatically detect intranet network", Uncheck "Include all local (intranet) sites not listed in other zones" will achieve the same effect, but can break NTLM/passthru authentication to local resources on corporate/domain networks.

Comment: Seems simply checking `Automatically detect intranet network` also works without touching the second checkbox, tested with resources from `file:///` as well as `https://` connecting back to `ws://localhost:8182` and `wss://localhost:8181` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the website to the zone of trusted sites at IE | Tools | Internet Options | Security and try again.

Comment: This solution won't work for localhost or 127.0.0.1 on IE10 or higher due to Enhanced Protection Mode.

Source:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/03/23/understanding-ie10-enhanced-protected-mode-network-security-addons-cookies-metro-desktop.aspx