# Excel office addin + React - Security Error with websockets

Tags: websocket, office-js, office-addins, officedev, office-js-helpers

I've been trying to create an excel addin with React. I'm trying to connect it to a websocket server but I keep getting this vague error: `Error: SecurityError` due to this line `this.client = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:6789')`.

Is there a way to disable this security? The addin is using the IE/Edge browser to host the runtime process.

Comment: I'm getting it too for Outlook addin, so far I have not found a solution. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979870/web-socket-client-connection-issue-in-windows-8-1-ie-11-loopback-not-allowed) helps, but I can't test it because those setting are getting managed by entrerprise in my case.

Comment: I tried those internet options but to no avail. Its really odd/frustrating that they require SSL/TLS over localhost websocket connections. I'm just trying to get data from a different piece of software running on the same machine..